# Unity dependency injection for Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've just started using Unity with MVC and I'm running into, what I see as, a bit of code duplication. Consider the following Controller/Model pattern:

**Controller:**

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly IDependency1 _dependency1;
    private readonly IDependency2 _dependency2;
    private readonly IDependency3 _dependency3;

    public MyController(
        IDependency1 dependency1,
        IDependency2 dependency2,
        IDependency3 dependency3
    ) {

    }

    public ActionResult Thingy() {
        var model = new Thingy(_dependency1, _dependency2, _dependency3);
        model.DoLogic();
        model.SetUpView();
        model.Finalize();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class Thingy {
    private readonly IDependency1 _dependency1;
    private readonly IDependency2 _dependency2;
    private readonly IDependency3 _dependency3;

    public Thingy(
        IDependency1 dependency1,
        IDependency2 dependency2,
        IDependency3 dependency3
    ) {

    }

    // Now I can use my dependencies
}
```

This allows me to implement skinny controllers/fat models, however I am now duplicating dependencies in both Controller & Model.

I saw that I can use attributes in my model:

```
public class Thingy {
    [Dependency]
    public IDependency1 Dependency1 { private get; set; };
    [Dependency]
    public IDependency2 Dependency2 { private get; set; };
    [Dependency]
    public IDependency3 Dependency3 { private get; set; };
}
```

Then initialize my model in my action like so:

```
public ActionResult Thingy() {
    // No need to pass in via constructor
    var model = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Thingy>();
}
```

Nice & lean from a coding POV, but I read that this is an anti-pattern?

**Q: Why is this considered an anti-pattern and can I modify my structure to prevent code duplication?**

Comment: Why would you want a fat model? Do you really think your model should be aware of the view? Could this model be used in web / mobile / embedded (re-used generally)? Shouldn't the Controller be the one doing the "thinking" and arranging things. The View should show the data. The Model IS the data?

Comment: The anti-pattern here is that your model contains dependencies. A model should be a plain old DTO; just data, no behavior. You should only return data objects back to the view, since the view can't (easily) be tested, and moving logic into the model increases complexity.

Comment: I see, that makes sense - thanks to both - I'll refactor the Controller :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is anti-pattern. One reason - excess relatedness code. If you want to replace IoC container (for example the NInject) then you have to change the code of the controller and model. It violates Open/closed principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Also, you will be hard to do unit testing controller.